# Can we not do this

Tags: discussion

My question

[What is the difference between sex cults, and the tantric tradition?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/39903/what-is-the-difference-between-sex-cults-and-the-tantric-tradition)

is entirely valid, there's no need to be offended by it, as you don't even practice in those traditions. One would like to think that if you did you could answer it completely - as it's no rhetorical question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't vote to close the question -- I downvoted it for what seemed to me a lack of research effort and of clarity. That's what a downvote on a question is supposed to mean, I'm not sure what your complaint is.

I then commented to reference existing topics on the site, in case in case you'd like to read further.

And I gather that the topic you're asking about may be considered "[esoteric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vajrayana#Esoteric_transmission)' -- asking a question like, "So how is tantra not a sex cult?" is kind of tactless IMO.

Then, in a comment, you asked me whether I know what the word "sex" means? I'm not especially offended, but I don't see how to answer in a way that would be helpful etc.

Comment: i think calling it "tactless" is "tasteless"

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/chacun_%C3%A0_son_go%C3%BBt

Comment: yeah i guess so. -2 i quite extreme, though i do trust that it won't break site